# How to hide Pie char legend?

Tags: blazor, blazorise

Im beginner to Blazorise  and [Blazorise Chart component](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/chart), does any one know how to hide pie chart legend

[image]

**here is my code**

```
<Chart @ref="pieChart" Type="ChartType.Pie" TItem="double" Options="@chartOptions"  />




@*Pie chart*@

@code {
    private Chart<double> pieChart;

    ChartOptions chartOptions = new() { AspectRatio = 0.5 };
     
    private string[] Labels = { "Below 45 day's", "90 to 45 day's", "More than 90 day's", };
    private List<string> backgroundColors = new() { ChartColor.FromRgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2f), ChartColor.FromRgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2f), ChartColor.FromRgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2f), ChartColor.FromRgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2f), ChartColor.FromRgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2f), ChartColor.FromRgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2f) };
    private List<string> borderColors = new() { ChartColor.FromRgba(255, 99, 132, 1f), ChartColor.FromRgba(54, 162, 235, 1f), ChartColor.FromRgba(255, 206, 86, 1f), ChartColor.FromRgba(75, 192, 192, 1f), ChartColor.FromRgba(153, 102, 255, 1f), ChartColor.FromRgba(255, 159, 64, 1f) };

    private bool isAlreadyInitialised;

    private Random random = new(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!isAlreadyInitialised)
        {
            isAlreadyInitialised = true;

            await HandleRedraw(pieChart, GetPieChartDataset);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleRedraw<TDataSet, TItem, TOptions, TModel>(Blazorise.Charts.BaseChart<TDataSet, TItem, TOptions, TModel> chart, Func<TDataSet> getDataSet)
        where TDataSet : ChartDataset<TItem>
        where TOptions : ChartOptions
        where TModel : ChartModel
    {
        await chart.Clear();

        await chart.AddLabelsDatasetsAndUpdate(Labels, getDataSet());
    }

    private int pieLabel;

    private PieChartDataset<double> GetPieChartDataset()
    {
        return new()
        {
            Label = $"#{++pieLabel} of randoms",
            Data = RandomizeData(),
            BackgroundColor = backgroundColors,
            BorderColor = borderColors,
            BorderWidth = 1,
            
        };
    }
     
    List<double> RandomizeData() => RandomizeData(3, 50);

    List<double> RandomizeData(int min, int max)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => random.Next(min, max) * random.NextDouble()).ToList();
    }

  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ChartOptions` you need to set the `Plugins` property and then inside plugins set the `Legend` property and set `Display` to `false`.

```
ChartOptions chartOptions = new() {
    AspectRatio = 1.5,
    Plugins = new ChartPlugins
    {
        Legend = new ChartLegend
        {
            Display = false
        }
    }
};
```